# VBA - How to return a single value from array using SUMIFS?

Tags: arrays, vba, sumifs

I'm trying to write up some code but am running into an unexpected issue and was hoping someone here could help.

Basically I have a set of data (about 150k rows) and have used VBA to read them into an array. Now I want to apply a SUMIFS function on this array, however I keep getting an array returned rather than a single value. I'm using something along the lines of:

```
With Application
    OutputArray(1, 1) = .SumIfs(.Index(MyArray, 0, 1), .Index(MyArray, 0, 2), ">0")
End With
```

Now, I can use a .Sum in this way and get a single value. When applying the exact same .SumIfs function as used in the VBA directly on the worksheet I also get a single value, but in the VBA code all I'm getting is an array of type Error.

The sum range are all Double type. The output array is a Variant.

If I'm missing any additional information, please let me know.

Comment: `.Index` returns a single value, but `.SumIfs` expects Range. If you can, try that as Excel Formula and post it so I can get better idea of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Actually, putting a 0 for row or column argument will use the whole range and as such runs fine. I mentioned above I have ran the exact same query as an excel formula which also worked. This is the formula: =SUMIFS(INDEX(A2:G154794,0,6),INDEX(A2,G154794,0,4),"31")

Comment: Interesting .. in Google Sheets `=INDEX({1,2;3,4},0,2)` results in `{2;4}`, but I don't have Excel at home to test it. Can you tell me what is the return type of `test = Application.Index(MyArray, 0, 1)` from the [Locals](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting/8020/debugger-locals-window#t=201611251509367841724) window?

Comment: Yeah, that's the exact functionality of Excel as 2 and 4 are both in the second column. The type is Variant/Variant(1 to 154975, 1 to 7). For the second dim, types are String, String, String, String, Date, Double, Boolean.

Comment: That seems strange because I was expecting `, 1 to 1)` for the second dimension (meaning one column)

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload a sample of the data you are trying to apply the Sumifs to? And have you defined the size of the Outputarray first with `Redim`?...have you tried wrapping the .Sumifs(.... with a `.Sum` ?

Comment: Hi Nick, I can't supply the data unfortunately. The dimensions for the output array have been defined, yes.

Comment: I have also tried wrapping it with a .Sum, however it just sums the error and I just get Error as a result.

Comment: Ok are you absolutely sure the data you are trying to sum are numerical values? If some are not then you will get this error. Some numbers may be stored as text so try using the `ISTEXT()` function on a new column to check.It returns True or false.

Comment: If the range wasn't numerical then the replication on the worksheet wouldn't work either I would imagine? I tried the ISTEXT() formula on the worksheet though just to verify and there is no data stored as text.

Comment: Ill have to test this with actual data then.